# How to retrieve firebase list using adapter

Tags: android, json, firebase, android-recyclerview, admob

I am trying to retrieve data from firebase database with putting ads in every 8 items. I have created my Adapter "posts_adapter", but I don't know how to retrieve data to show them at recycler view. Can anybody help me please by showing how I can retrieve data from firebase to recycler view with admob.

Here's my Adapter:

```
public class posts_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int Posts_View = 0;

private static final int AD_MOB_View = 1;

private final List<retrieve_data> mPosts_List;


public posts_adapter(List<retrieve_data> mPosts_List) {
    this.mPosts_List = mPosts_List;}


@Override public int getItemCount() {return mPosts_List.size();}


@Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {return (position % 8 == 0) ? AD_MOB_View : Posts_View;}


@Override public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case Posts_View:
            View posts_view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.posts_handler_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new Posts_View_Holder(posts_view);
        case AD_MOB_View:

        default:View ad_view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_handler_view, viewGroup, false);
            return new NativeExpressAdViewHolder(ad_view);}

}

private class Posts_View_Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    Posts_View_Holder(View view) {
        super(view);
        //POSTS VIEW
    }
}

private class NativeExpressAdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    NativeExpressAdViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);

        //AD VIEW
    }
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    switch (viewType) {
        case Posts_View:

            //Retrieve data for posts

            break;

        case AD_MOB_View:

            //Retrieve data from ads

        default:

    }
}
```

}

And here's my JSON:

```js
 },
  "posts" : {
    "-Ks7yUeMgNpPM5P8nF_7" : {
      "describe" : "Hello world",
      "location" : "USA, NY",
      "latlng" : "0,0",
      "photo" : "null",
      "time" : 1503389171,
      "uid" : "8J1lF6awbAVWm8ruJEKUNWcuG512"
    }
  },
```

And Here's my Class:

```
mMain_RecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.Main_RecyclerView);
    mMain_RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mMain_RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
```

Please help me how to use adapter in recycler view with admob every 8 views.

Comment: have you tried looking at this example - https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample

Comment: Of curse, but I couldn't understand very will ... So I need only a simple way not advanced.. so please help me if possible..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly... You should retrieve the data in your fragment of activity you are making this adapter for and pass the retrieved object OR arraylist of objects in your adapter through it's constructor.

It's never a good idea to retrieve or send data from/to the network through your adapter. Since the networking process might take some time and you wouldn't want that in your adapter.

Eg.

1. Inside ACTIVITY/FRAGMENT

`FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();`

2. Then create a reference to your path
3. Retrieve your data and store it in an object or `arrayList` using the `addOnComlpleteListener`
4. Pass the `arrayList` or object to the constructor of your adapter
5. Here you will have the `arrayList` or object you passed previously and you can use the data they carry